# Aurelia with JSPM fails to load aurelia-pal-browser.js

Tags: aurelia, systemjs, jspm

So my question is very similar to this one: [SystemJS (Aurelia with jspm) fails to load "aurelia-pal-browser" from jspm_packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522750/systemjs-aurelia-with-jspm-fails-to-load-aurelia-pal-browser-from-jspm-packa) , however the solution there does not work for me.  Also my error is slightly different.

> system.src.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/app/aurelia-pal-browser.js
>       Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/app/aurelia-pal-browser.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:9000/app/aurelia-pal-browser.js

It seems that System.js is trying to load `aurelia-pal-browser.js` from my `app` folder (this is my main code folder).  I have my config.js `paths` as:

```
paths: {
  "*": "app/*.js",
  "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
  "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
},
```

Other than that my app is super bare bones, this is my first attempt an Aurelia project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found this github issue: https://github.com/aurelia/bootstrapper/issues/55 which got me going in the right direction.  It turns out that I needed to add the following to my `config.js` `map` object:

```
"aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.2.0",
```

As mentioned in the git hub issue I placed this directly after the `"aurelia-framework"` element in the map and that solved my problem.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future. (Or it's fixed soon)

Comment: This has been so valuable!

Answer (score 0):

I'd also point out that if you're using Visual Studio that the file needs to be included in the project's folder structure. It may be on disk and just needs to be included