# Getting jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jspm

I am getting the following error:

```
system.src.js:1041 GET http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js 404 (Not Found)
W @ system.src.js:1041
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1777
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1776
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:2801
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3379
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3711
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4103
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4568
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4837
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:408
Promise.then (async)
s @ system.src.js:402
i @ system.src.js:388
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:544
a @ system.src.js:342
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:838
Promise.then (async)
import @ system.src.js:831
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1800
(anonymous) @ (index):24
system.src.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js
```

I have tried the following linked solution but it is not working. 
[SystemJS (Aurelia with jspm) fails to load "aurelia-pal-browser" from jspm_packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522750/systemjs-aurelia-with-jspm-fails-to-load-aurelia-pal-browser-from-jspm-packa)

I am have run both jspm install and npm install multiple times.

Trying to access the js file in the browser results in the error:

```
Cannot GET /jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1.js
```

I tried accessing other files as well and it seems that the only folder that is accessible is /jspm_packages/ but not the sub folders.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I took the whole directory of the project from another colleague.
From his folder everything works fine.

I read somewhere these things might be a result of bugs in jspm.

In any case this was a work around.